# How to check if at least 2 checkboxes are marked in order to continue?

Tags: php, checkbox

How to require at least 2 checkboxes to be checked in order to continue? I have the following php:

```
/**
     * check_required_addons function.
     *
     * @access private
     * @param mixed $product_id
     * @return void
     */
    private function check_required_addons( $product_id ) {
        $addons = get_product_addons( $product_id, false, false, true ); // No parent addons, but yes to global

        if ( $addons && ! empty( $addons ) ) {
            foreach ( $addons as $addon ) {
                if ( '1' == $addon['required'] ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Where $addons = array(); and within this array there are the checkboxes. How to check at least 2 checkboxes to be marked in order to continue?

Comment: Use if(count($addons)>=2){ return true;}

Comment: @SunilPachlangia simple count not enough, `$addon['required']` must be 1 to count it

Comment: @cske Judging by the text, both the title and content, it is enough. However, the code does not seem to match the question...

Comment: @SunilPachlangia i assume that code checks for having at least one required addon, and shoud be modified to check for at least two. But question needs clarification...

Comment: Every addon has an array of checkbox fields.

Answer (score 3):

```
private function check_required_addons( $product_id ) {
                $addons = get_product_addons($product_id, false, false, true ); // No parent addons, but yes to global

                if ( $addons && ! empty( $addons ) ) {
                  $count = 0;
                    foreach ( $addons as $addon ) {
                        if ( '1' == $addon['required'] ) {
                            $count++;
                        }
                    }
                   if($count >= 2){
                       return true;
                   }
                }

                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

```
/**
     * check_required_addons function.
     *
     * @access private
     * @param mixed $product_id
     * @return void
     */
    private function check_required_addons( $product_id ) {
        $addons = get_product_addons( $product_id, false, false, true ); // No parent addons, but yes to global

        if ( is_array($addons)) {
            return 1 < array_sum(array_column($addons,'required'));  
        }

        return false;
    }
```